# Creating an Entity Key in code for a table that has a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am trying to create an Entity key for a table, in order to insert a row in the table without loading the related tables.

I am trying to use this contructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739024.aspx

The code example in the above link uses a different contructor.

The code I have so far is:

```
KeyValuePair<String, Object> key1 = new KeyValuePair<string,object>("MainId", 1);
KeyValuePair<String, Object> key2 = new KeyValuePair<string,object>("SubId", 2);


List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> keyList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>();
keyList.Add(key1);
keyList.Add(key2);


EntityKey entitykey = new EntityKey(
```

How can I complete the creation of the entity key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object value = null;
keyList.TryGetValue("MainId", out value);
EntityKey entitykey = new EntityKey("EntitySetName.TableName", "FieldName", value);
```

**Edit:**
To add multiple keys:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entityKeyValues =
 new KeyValuePair<string, object>[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Key", "Value") };
EntityKey key = new EntityKey("EntitySetName.TableName", entityKeyValues);
```

That should do the work.

Comment: This works when there is a key with a single field, but I have a key with "FieldName1" and "FieldName2"